# sorting a multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I have an array of arrays, as such

```
$statuses = array(
  [0] => array('id'=>10, 'status' => 'active'),
  [1] => array('id'=>11, 'status' => 'closed'),
  [2] => array('id'=>12, 'status' => 'active'),
  [3] => array('id'=>13, 'status' => 'stopped'),
)
```

I want to be able to make a new array of arrays and each of those sub arrays would contain the elements based on if they had the same status. 
The trick here is, I do not want to do a case check based on hard coded status names as they can be random. I want to basically do a dynamic comparison, and say "if you are unique, then create a new array and stick yourself in there, if an array already exists with the same status than stick me in there instead". A sample result could look something like this.

Ive really had a challenge with this because the only way I can think to do it is check every single element against every other single element, and if unique than create a new array. This gets out of control fast if the original array is larger than 100. There must be some built in functions that can make this efficient.

```
<?php
$sortedArray = array(
    ['active'] => array(
        array(
            'id' => 10,
            'status' => 'active'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 12,
            'status' => 'active'
        )
    ),
    ['closed'] => array(
        array(
            'id' => 11,
            'status' => 'active'
        )
    ),
    ['stopped'] => array(
        array(
            'id' => 13,
            'status' => 'active'
        )
    ),
)
```

Comment: `foreach($arr as $child) { $newarr[$child['status']][] = $child; }`

Comment: Well I'll be damned. That worked perfectly. I was going to do something ridiculously complicated. thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$SortedArray = array();
$SortedArray['active'] = array();
$SortedArray['closed'] = array();
$SortedArray['stopped'] = array();

foreach($statuses as $Curr) {
    if ($Curr['status'] == 'active') { $SortedArray['active'][] = $Curr; }
    if ($Curr['status'] == 'closed') { $SortedArray['closed'][] = $Curr;  }
    if ($Curr['status'] == 'stopped') { $SortedArray['stopped'][] = $Curr;  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with functional way though it's pretty the same like [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491655/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php#comment64384778_38491655) said.

```
$sorted = array_reduce($statuses, function($carry, $status) {
    $carry[$status['status']][] = $status;
    return $carry;
}, []);
```